# Expected behaviour of freopen() with regards to buffering (setvbuf())?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, standards, standard-library, c-standard-library

In an attempt to [implement freopen()](http://pdclib.rootdirectory.de), I've come up to a piece of specification in the standard that doesn't actually specify anything, as far as I can see.

So... `freopen()` will close the stream (ignoring errors), clear its error and EOF flag, reset wide orientation, and then reopen the stream with the given mode. That much is clear; this is basically an fclose() / fopen(). Even if it isn't defined that way, it is pretty clear that this is what was intended.

However, I have two questions with regards to the things `setvbuf()` could have done to the stream -- setting a user-allocated buffer, and / or changing buffer policy.

---

**Question 1.**

1) Is `freopen()` expected to revert things to the default state, as if it had actually called `fopen()`? Or is it expected to carry over to the new stream whatever the user did set via `setvbuf()` on the old? This refers to both buffer memory and buffer policy, but the main issue here is with buffer memory.

The specification for `fclose()` specifies that any buffer the user associated with the stream via `setvbuf()` is disassociated, i.e. can now be `free()`'d by the user.

But `freopen()` only specifies that it *closes* the file associated with the stream, not that it `fclose()`es it.

So, after `freopen()`, is user-associated buffer memory still associated with the stream?

---

**Question 2.**

`freopen()` can conceivably be used on a `FILE` structure that is not actually associated with an open file at the time of the call (as errors trying to close the file are to be ignored).

That file structure could have been a previously open stream with user-assigned buffer memory and buffer policy. Is `freopen()` to honor these settings, i.e. re-associate the buffer memory / policy with the "re"-opened file, or is it to reinit the structure to defaults, assuming the user `free()`d the buffer memory after `fclose()`ing the file previously?

---

**My take.**

Looking at Q2, I don't see a way for the standard library to reliably determine whether a not-currently-open `FILE` structure with user-allocated buffer memory still "owns" that buffer memory, or whether the user has already reclaimed that memory. (That memory could conceivably be local, i.e. not part of the memory lists handled by `malloc()` / `free()` even if I were willing to go there -- and this would be very much uncharacteristically involved work expected of standard library functions.)

Similar considerations for buffer policy.

So the only *reliable* way of handling things, as far as I can see, is for `freopen()` to handle the closing of "any file that is associated with the specified stream" as a "real" `fclose()`, and re-set buffer memory / policyto defaults.

Am I right in this understanding, or is there an alternative answer to Q1 / Q2?

Comment: freopen returns a new FILE* for the new stream. The FILE* passed as a parameter is closed. It would be unexpected to copy the buffer setting.

Comment: @stark: By definition, the `FILE *` returned is either `NULL` in case of error, or *the same `FILE *` as passed as argument to the function* ("...the value of stream"). So unfortunately it is not as clear-cut as that.

Comment: It is an obvious optimization to reuse the storage, but the description of the function is that it is a new stream.

Comment: @stark: I disagree both with the "obvious" and the "new stream". (And the wording of the standard backs me up on this.) If that's your answer, post it, but as a comment this is not helpful. (Comments should be for clarifying the question, not attempts to answer it.)

Comment: Kudos for tackling this undertaking... I will try and contribute, having invested some time for the same goal. You add a `filename` slot in the `FILE` structure to implement the questionable specification of `freopen(NULL, mode, stream)`: I doubt this is necessary nor sufficient and you have a silly bug in the implementation: `stream->filename = (char *)malloc( strlen( filename ) )`. Definitely use `strdup()` which is finally making its way into the next C Standard.

Comment: Your link currently resolves to https://pdclib.rootdirectory.de/, and I'm getting a "404 Not Found".  I'll just note that copying the filename isn't sufficient to guarantee being able to reopen it later.  The process could call `chdir()` to reset its current working directory or even `chroot()` to changes its root directory.  Probably the most robust way to handle those possibilities would be to `open()` the current working directory on the first `fopen()` and keep an open file descriptor, then use `openat()` and that file descriptor to reopen the file on `freopen()` calls.

Comment: (cont) **BUT** that open file descriptor could open up a way out of a `chroot` jail on systems that have `fchroot()` (BSD, Solaris, maybe Linux?) You'd definitely want to set the `O_CLOXEC` or `FD_CLOEXEC`  close-on-exec flag on that file descriptor.

Comment: Let's not get into what's currently there. 1) As the comments indicate, I am in the process of completely rewriting the current (rather old) implementation, and 2) the whole point of the project is to *minimize* and *isolate* OS-specific code, so I will not splatter POSIX calls all across the implementation. Thanks for the hints, but let's focus on the actual question, and not paint the bikeshed. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The C standard does not state the the buffering state is modified in any way.

The entire [C11 `freopen()` specification](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.4) is (including [footnote 272](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note272)):

> **7.21.5.4 The `freopen` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup></sub>
>
> ```
>      #include <stdio.h>
>      FILE *freopen(const char * restrict filename,
>           const char * restrict mode,
>           FILE * restrict stream);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> <sub><sup>2</sup></sub> The `freopen` function opens the file whose name is the string pointed
>   to by `filename` and associates the stream pointed to by stream with it.
>   The `mode` argument is used just as in the `fopen` function.<sup>272)</sup>
>
> <sub><sup>3</sup></sub> If `filename` is a null pointer, the `freopen` function attempts to
>   change the mode of the stream to that specified by `mode`, as if the
>   name of the file currently associated with the stream had been used.
>   It is implementation-defined which changes of mode are permitted (if
>   any), and under what circumstances.
>
> <sub><sup>4</sup></sub> The `freopen` function first attempts to close any file that is
>   associated with the specified stream. Failure to close the file is
>   ignored. The error and end-of-file indicators for the stream are
>   cleared.
>
> **Returns**
>
> <sub><sup>5</sup></sub> The `freopen` function returns a null pointer if the open operation
>   fails. Otherwise, `freopen` returns the value of `stream`.
>
> ---
>
> <sub><sup>272)</sup> The primary use of the `freopen` function is to change the file
>   associated with a standard text stream (`stderr`, `stdin`, or `stdout`), as
>   those identifiers need not be modifiable lvalues to which the value
>   returned by the `fopen` function may be assigned.</sub>

To me, the key phrase is *associates the stream pointed to by stream with it.* The preexisting *stream pointed to by `stream`* has a new file *associated* with it - and that's all.  By not specifying any changes to the buffering, that implies to me that the current buffer state is retained, as `freopen()` is just *associating* a new file and mode with the **preexisting** stream.  Only those changes to the `FILE *` stream explicitly noted in the standard should be made, by my reading.

Note also in paragraph 4:  *The `freopen` function first attempts to close any file that is associated with the specified stream.*  Again, the standard refers to *the specified stream*.

To me, the conclusion seems inescapable:  `freopen()` does not create a new stream.  It just points the preexisting stream at a new file - and that's all it does.

This reading - that the current stream's buffer status is not modified - is supported by current implementations.  They do not modify the buffering state of the preexisting stream.

Neither the [GLIBC `freopen()` implementation](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/freopen.c.html) nor [the OpenSolaris/Illumos implementation](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/4e0c5eff9af325c80994e9527b7cb8b3a1ffd1d4/usr/src/lib/libc/port/stdio/fopen.c#L197) (very likely to be the current Solaris implementation) seem to modify the status of the original buffering other than flushing any buffer before closing the file.

The `freopen()` function does appear to be poorly specified.  [POSIX has this to say](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html#tag_16_168_07):

> **APPLICATION USAGE**
>
> The `freopen()` function is typically used to attach the pre-opened streams associated with `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` to other files.
>
> Since implementations are not required to support any stream mode changes when the `pathname` argument is `NULL`, portable applications cannot rely on the use of `freopen()` to change the stream mode, and use of this feature is discouraged. The feature was originally added to the ISO C standard in order to facilitate changing `stdin` and `stdout` to binary mode. Since a `'b'` character in the mode has no effect on POSIX systems, this use of the feature is unnecessary in POSIX applications. However, even though the `'b'` is ignored, a successful call to `freopen (NULL, "wb", stdout)` does have an effect. In particular, for regular files it truncates the file and sets the file-position indicator for the stream to the start of the file. It is possible that these side-effects are an unintended consequence of the way the feature is specified in the ISO/IEC 9899:1999 standard, but unless or until the ISO C standard is changed, applications which successfully call `freopen (NULL, "wb", stdout)` will behave in unexpected ways on conforming systems in situations such as:
>
> ```
> { appl file1; appl file2; } > file3
> ```
>
> which will result in *file3* containing only the output from the second invocation of **appl**.

Comment: This makes things "funny" when the `FILE *` passed as argument is not a currently `fopen()`ed stream. It could point to a *former* stream, in which case it would be properly initialized (including buffer metainformation, i.e. whether library-controlled or user controlled)... but as the stream is *closed* at this point, user-controlled buffer memory *could* conceivably have already been `free()`d. Or the structure isn't initialized at all... that's the point I am worrying about the most. What am I (as `freopen()` implementor) expected to do here? I don't see any way to *verify* the metadata...

Comment: @DevSolar All true.  The only thing I can think of is do some testing to see how current implementations handle such situations.  I suspect if you used GLIBC, closed a stream, freed the buffer you allocated for that stream, and then use `freopen()` on that stream, and it fails, the response to any bug report filed would be "Don't free the buffer for a preexisting stream then expect that stream to work later."

Comment: Testing on Raspian and Mint, I found that glibc does **not** keep buffer policy **or** buffer across calls to `freopen()`. The stream is apparently completely re-initialized.